# Why does "jumpForce" change automatically in the Inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D platformer with Unity. I want my game to support both keyboard and gamepad, so I use the new Input System and the Player Input component.

My problem is that when I press the jump button, the player doesn't jump properly. In fact, it can jump at the beginning of the game but after that it can't jump anymore, and just moves upwards at a low height.

I minimized the game window, pressed Play, and found that after the first jump, the `jumpForce` value changes automatically from 300 to 1. I want to know why this is happening and how I can fix it.

Thanks in advance.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour, PlayerInputActions.IPlayerActions
 {
   private PlayerInputActions controls;     
   private Rigidbody2D rb;
   private Animator anim;
   private bool facingRight = true;
   private Vector2 moveInput;
  [SerializeField] private float jumpForce;
    float JumpPressedRemember = 0;
   
   [SerializeField] float JumpPressedRememberTime = 0.2f;
    float GroundedRemember = 0;
     
   [SerializeField]  float GroundedRememberTime = 0.25f;  
   [SerializeField]  float HorizontalAcceleration = 1;
   [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float HorizontalDampingBasic = 0.5f;
   [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float HorizontalDampingWhenStopping = 0.5f;
   [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float HorizontalDampingWhenTurning = 0.5f;
   [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float JumpHeight = 0.5f;

   private void Awake() 
   {
      controls = new PlayerInputActions();

      controls.Player.SetCallbacks(this);
    }
     void Start()
    {
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
      anim = GetComponent<Animator>();       
}
   void PlayerInputActions.IPlayerActions.OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
   {
      moveInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
          
   }

   void PlayerInputActions.IPlayerActions.OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
   {
       jumpForce = context.ReadValue<float>();
       switch (context.phase)
       {
            case InputActionPhase.Performed:
               this.Jump();
               break;
       }
   }

  void PlayerInputActions.IPlayerActions.OnShoot(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
  {
      
  }

   
   public void Jump()
   {
     rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * this.jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Force) ;
     

     
   }

  void FixedUpdate()
  {

   if(facingRight == false && moveInput.x > 0){
   
    Flip();
   
   }else if (facingRight == true && moveInput.x < 0){
    
    Flip();

   }
 }
    void Flip(){
    
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
    Scaler.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = Scaler;
    
 }  
     

 void OnEnable()
 {
     controls.Enable();
 }
 
 void OnDisable()
 {
     controls.Disable();
 }
 void Update()
  {

   Vector2 GroundedBoxCheckPosition = (Vector2)transform.position + new Vector2(0, -0.01f);
   Vector2  GroundedBoxCheckScale = (Vector2)transform.localScale + new Vector2(-0.02f, 0);
   bool Grounded = Physics2D.OverlapBox(GroundedBoxCheckPosition, transform.localScale, 0);
    
    GroundedRemember -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (Grounded)
    {
      GroundedRemember = GroundedRememberTime;
    }

    JumpPressedRemember -= Time.deltaTime; 
   if (controls.Player.Jump.triggered)
   {
      JumpPressedRemember = JumpPressedRememberTime;
   }
     if (controls.Player.Jump.triggered)
        {
            if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * JumpHeight);
            }
        }
    if ((JumpPressedRemember > 0) && (GroundedRemember > 0))
    {
       JumpPressedRemember = 0;
       GroundedRemember = 0;

      rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
    }
     float HorizontalVelocity = rb.velocity.x;
      HorizontalVelocity += moveInput.x;
          
    
        if (Mathf.Abs(moveInput.x) < 0.01f)
            HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingWhenStopping, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
           else if (Mathf.Sign(moveInput.x) != Mathf.Sign(HorizontalVelocity))
           HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingWhenTurning, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
        else
            HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingBasic, Time.deltaTime * 10f);

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(HorizontalVelocity, rb.velocity.y);    
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean `jumpForce` is changing. Is it possible that the value you're reading is normalized between 0 and 1? You might try making jump force a constant and multiplying it by that value.

Comment: Yes, I meant jumpForce. Could you please be more specific or show it in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read your script, i dont know all the functionalities of all the other scripts but i think i have found your problem:

```
 void PlayerInputActions.IPlayerActions.OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
   {
       jumpForce = context.ReadValue<float>();  <-- HERE you set your jumpforce to something!!!
       switch (context.phase)
       {
            case InputActionPhase.Performed:
               this.Jump();
               break;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried what you said but when I write any number within the parentheses, an error occurs saying "No overload for method 'ReadValue' takes 1 arguments [Assembly-CSharp] ".

Comment: yeah, i think you need to fully remove that line and try again.

Comment: If I remove that line, the player jumps out of the screen. This is not a good idea. Perhaps there is something that I need to change but don't know what that is.

Comment: that is wierd,cause you are using a context.ReadLine . but unafortunately i don't know what the problem is then